# Spring - Validate the field of a field

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I am developing an API with Spring boot in which I have an object which has another object which has a field that I need to validate. These are the following:

**CodigoDTO**

```
public final class CodigoDTO {
    private String codigo;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String accion;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private UserDTO user;
}
```

**UserDTO**

```
public final class UserDTO {
    @ValidIdDocument(message = ERROR_DNI_NIE_FORMAT, checkNie = true, checkNif = true)
    private String username;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;
    private String email;
    @Telefono
    private String tlf;
    private List<CategoriaVideosExplicativos> videosExplicativosVistos;
}
```

**Validator interface**

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { TelefonoValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface Telefono {
    String message() default ERROR_EMAIL_OR_TLF;
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I am not including the validator interface because it's not relevant.

So, the thing is that I am sending a `CodigoDTO` object to my service, which has an `UserDTO` and whose `tlf` field must have a certain pattern. But the validator is not being triggered.

Please, notice that I know I can put the annotation in the `UserDTO` field in `CodigoDTO` instead but that doesn't feel like it's the right way to do it.

How could I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: go to the service which consumes the object and annotate it with @Valid. this should do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to validate the nested object, you have to annotate the field with `@Valid`annotation:

```
public final class CodigoDTO {
    private String codigo;
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String accion;
    @Valid
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private UserDTO user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the service which consumes the object and annotate the object with @Valid. this should do the work.

```
public String myService( @RequestBody @Valid myObject) {
 //something  
}
```